# Pairing Similar objects of an array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a list of routers in array called routerList. I want to display the active router next to the backup router in my view. The router object in the array has an attribute called HostName that has the locationID_Router#_RouterName, for instance WA34_R01_ABCABC. Somewhere in the array is another router that is its pair with the name WA34_R02_ABCABC. I want to reorder the array so when I use ng-repeat those two routers and all the other matched pairs will be next to each other. I wrote a function that will tell me if the names are the same minus 1 character so R01 and R02. Here:

```
        function stringCompare(word1, word2){
        var differences = 0;
        if(word1 != word2){
            if(word1.length == word2.length){
                for(i=0; i <= word1.length-1; i++){
                    if(word1.charAt(i) != word2.charAt(i)){
                        differences +=1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(differences == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        };
    };
```

I then tried to have a loop within a loop to get the pairs and add them to a new array as it found the pairs but I keep getting errors of cannot read HostName part way through the loop.

```
function findCouples(array){
            var MatchedRouters = [];
            for(i=0;i<=array.length-1;i++){
                for(var i2=0;i2<=array.length-1;i2++){
                    if(stringCompare(array[i].HostName,array[i2].HostName)){
                        MatchedRouters.push(array[i]);
                        MatchedRouters.push(array[i2]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return MatchedRouters
        };
```

If there is a better way to do this PLEASE let me know! If not any help you could give me for getting it to work like this would be amazing.
Thanks!!

Comment: In Javascript arrays have methods like forEach so you don't have to write out the for loop. Also I think it might be easier to create a different data structure for display. Can you share you HTML for displaying the list?

Comment: Why not order them ascending directly?

Comment: I might be easier to have a data structure where something like routers= [ { location: 'location1', name:'name1', routers: { '1', '2' } }] for display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initally get your list or routers create the properties you need to sort on.

Something like:

```
routers.forEach(function(router) {
    router.location: getRouterLocation(router.HostName);
    router.number: getRouterNumber(router.HostName);
    router.name: getRouterName(router.HostName);
});
```

Then create your functions getRouterLocation, getRouterNumber, etc.. to parse out the values you need.

```
function getRouterLocation(hostName) {
    return hostName.substring(0, hostName.indexOf('_');
}
```

Comment: You're a genius!! Thank you. I just created a new array snagged the last part of the HostName and sorted the array on Name. So simple! Why did i go through all that extra effort haha

Comment: Great, glad I could help! :)